# Disable shading on deploy

Tags: java, maven

I am currently trying to figure out how not to deploy a shaded artifact to my maven repository.

My current project requires some modules to generate shaded artifacts that can be shared with users, but when deploying I only want to upload the original jar file - which only contains the stuff our developers need.

Is there a way to disable the shading goal when deploying a maven project?
Disabling deploy completely disables it, not just uploading the shaded JAR file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using the maven shade plugin?

If so you can add the following in your plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
          <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
          <shadedClassifierName>myclassifier</shadedClassifierName>
</configuration>
```

That will make maven shade plugin deploy both your original artifact and the shaded artifact (with classifier  `myclassifier`) to your repository.

Is that good enough? I'm not sure how you can disable deploying the shaded artifact entirely.

Comment: No, it is still trying to upload the massive JAR. I didnt have that option previously enabled and adding it set to "false" didn't do the trick either. Setting the "finalName" of the artifact did the trick though

Comment: @SpaceEmotion setting the `finalName` to what?

Comment: To just something else than the default value. I set mine to the original name suffixed with "shaded"